# How does grep know it is writing to the input file?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, grep

If I try to redirect the output of `grep` to the same file that it is reading from, like so:

```
$ grep stuff file.txt > file.txt
```

I get the error message `grep: input file 'file.txt' is also the output`. How does `grep` determine this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the GNU grep source code, the `grep` check the i-nodes of the input  and the output:

```
  if (!out_quiet && list_files == 0 && 1 < max_count
      && S_ISREG (out_stat.st_mode) && out_stat.st_ino
      && SAME_INODE (st, out_stat))   /* <------------------ */
    {
      if (! suppress_errors)
        error (0, 0, _("input file %s is also the output"), quote (filename));
      errseen = 1;
      goto closeout;
    }
```

The `out_stat` is filled by calling `fstat` against `STDOUT_FILENO`.

```
  if (fstat (STDOUT_FILENO, &tmp_stat) == 0 && S_ISREG (tmp_stat.st_mode))
    out_stat = tmp_stat;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I forgot about how the shell actually sets up the process's file descriptors beforehand and that grep could check info on these.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code - you can see that it checks for this case (the file is already open for reading by `grep`) and reports it, see the `SAME_INODE` check below:

```
  /* If there is a regular file on stdout and the current file refers
     to the same i-node, we have to report the problem and skip it.
     Otherwise when matching lines from some other input reach the
     disk before we open this file, we can end up reading and matching
     those lines and appending them to the file from which we're reading.
     Then we'd have what appears to be an infinite loop that'd terminate
     only upon filling the output file system or reaching a quota.
     However, there is no risk of an infinite loop if grep is generating
     no output, i.e., with --silent, --quiet, -q.
     Similarly, with any of these:
       --max-count=N (-m) (for N >= 2)
       --files-with-matches (-l)
       --files-without-match (-L)
     there is no risk of trouble.
     For --max-count=1, grep stops after printing the first match,
     so there is no risk of malfunction.  But even --max-count=2, with
     input==output, while there is no risk of infloop, there is a race
     condition that could result in "alternate" output.  */
  if (!out_quiet && list_files == 0 && 1 < max_count
      && S_ISREG (out_stat.st_mode) && out_stat.st_ino
      && SAME_INODE (st, out_stat))
    {
      if (! suppress_errors)
        error (0, 0, _("input file %s is also the output"), quote (filename));
      errseen = true;
      goto closeout;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to write back to some file:

```
grep stuff file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try pipline with cat or tac:

```
    cat file | grep 'searchpattern' > newfile
```

it's best practice and short for realization